# How to get a arm version libcheck_pic?

Tags: c, cross-compiling, snort

I am trying to cross compile snort2.9 to target arm,and I need libcheck_pic.a or .so.
if I "apt-get install check",I would acquire libcheck_pic.a in host's version,if I cross compile check's source code(0.15 or 0.11),I only got libcheck.a but no libcheck_pic.a.
What could I do now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thankful I got know the libcheck_pic.so is same with libcheck.so

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).